# pre-stratification(blocking) vs post-stratification

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, clinical-trials, stratification

$Q:$ When should I consider pre-stratification(blocking) vs post-stratification? From experiments, I would certainly consider pre-stratification but post-stratification seems to homogenize the sample after the study.

$Q':$ How do I justify each usage in general? Note that in ANOVA, blocking depends upon the efficiency of blocking. Thus blocking might not be preferred. However, I have never seen justification for post-stratification.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica It is self study question as post-stratification is never showing up in experimental design books I have read in the past. It shows up frequently in epidemiology papers though.